# Math.abs() reporting error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, math, jgrasp

I'm new to java and I'm trying to figure out how the Math functions work. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Here's the entire program:

```
    public class Math {

    public static void main(String args[])
      {
        double x = Math.abs(4); 
        System.out.println(x);   
      }
    }
```

When I try to compile it, jGRASP says, "Math.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    double x = Math.abs(4);"

Comment: Why are you abs-ing a constant in the first place?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how the function's supposed to work right now. ABS (4) is simple.

Comment: @Quirliom That's sort of like asking "Why are you writing a program that prints 'hello, world'"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You called your class `Math`, so the built-in [`java.lang.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class can't be resolved.  So Java thinks you're attempting to call your own `abs` method that doesn't exist.

Call your class something else, or refer to `Math.abs` with a fully qualified class name: `java.lang.Math.abs(4)`.

Comment: I tried changing the class name (and file name) to MyTest. I've still got the same error. Although java.lang.Math.abs(4) does work.

Comment: Delete Math.java and Math.class from your directory; your `Math` class is still being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
public class MyTest {

public static void main(String args[])
  {
    double x = java.lang.Math.abs(4); 
    System.out.println(x);   
  }
}
```